# How to print the raw devtools request sent by Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, fiddler, chrome-devtools-protocol

I see that Puppeteer used devtools protocol. I want to see what requests are sent by Puppeteer.

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

How can I modify the above simple program to print the devtools requests sent by Puppeteer?

### Edit

As the code is in Nodejs, I added the tag nodejs because the solution may be in Nodejs instead of Puppeteer.

### Edit

Fiddler is mentioned as relevant. So I add this tag as well.

Comment: why do you want to see them? and why do you want to print them from your program? it makes more sense to use Fiddler

Comment: Fiddler is irrelevant as I am not debugging a web app. I am trying to see what is underlying puppeteer.

Comment: it uses webservices so it is possible to setup Fiddler as proxy. but why do you need it?

Comment: I just want to see what is going on under the hood. How to use Fiddler to control devtools protocol?

Comment: under the hood there are webservice calls. chrome runs a webservice server. the protocol is documented here https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/

Comment: I want to have a way to translate whatever puppeteer code to devtools requests. Just a doc is not sufficient.

Comment: Fiddler acts as a HTTP proxy so you have to set HTTP proxy for Node.js and point it to 127.0.0.1:8888

Comment: but again. the details are boring. json sent forth and back. what is you goal?

Comment: As I said, I just want to see what is going on under the hood. Please don't ask the same question again and again.

Comment: Maybe see "Listening to the protocol" here: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/#monitor

Comment: @vsemozhebuty How to send the request with websocat? I got this. `$ echo '{"command":"Page.captureScreenshot","parameters":{"format": "jpeg"}}'  | websocat -n1 --jsonrpc ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/page/FC28287234A1C005E927770F55793B1B
{"error":{"code":-32700,"message":"JSON: comma or map end expected at position 37"}}`

Comment: That protocol definition looks like ProtoBuf. Fiddler is not good in visualizing ProtoBuf content. There was a plugin but it wasn't very good. A proxy that is good in ProtoBuf decoding is Charles Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [chrome-protocol-proxy](https://github.com/wendigo/chrome-protocol-proxy) it captures all the CDP messagee. There are few extra steps involved here.

1. Run google chrome in debug mode
2. start chrome-protocol-proxy
3. Start puppeteer using [puppeteer.connect()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#puppeteerconnectoptions)

Run following commads, you may have to change them accordingly

```
google-chrome-stable --remote-debugging-port=9222 --headless  # run chrome
chrome-protocol-proxy     # to display CDP messages
```

Remove this line from your code

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
```

Add this line

```
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({"browserURL":"localhost:9223"});
```

Instead of `browserURL` you can give `browserWSEndpoint` which you will get by cURL on `localhost:9223/json/version`

If you want to go more into detail of CDP and puppeteer you might want to look at [Gettig Started with CDP](https://github.com/aslushnikov/getting-started-with-cdp/blob/master/README.md)